# Splashscreen - first Time with shared preferences

Tags: android, splash-screen

Hello I would like to display an other splashscreen after the default one, if the App starts for the first time(right after installation e.g.)

So I wrote this. But the new Activity does not start it stays at the Splash screen. Can somebody say whats wrong with it?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class splash extends Activity {
         private Thread splashTread;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
                // run your one time code
                 Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, main.class);

                         startActivity(i);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
                editor.commit();


             // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
             splashTread = new Thread() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     try {
                         synchronized(this){

                                 //wait 2 sec
                                 wait(2000);
                         }

                     } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
                     finally {
                         finish();



                         //start a new activity
                         Intent i = new Intent();
                         i.setClass(splash.this, main.class);
                                 startActivity(i);

                         stop();
                     }
                 }
             };

             splashTread.start();

        }

    }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling setContentView in the activity you're calling?

Comment: yes. Thats shouldnt be the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I've seen, your code runs the same Activity (main) regardless of whether the launch is the first time or not. I'm assuming your purpose is to immediately launch the alternate splash screen if it's the first launch, otherwise to proceed to the main Activity after 2 seconds. Also, I would recommend using a Handler rather than a Thread, since you're only making use of it once, and on a delay. Try this:

```
    public class splash extends Activity
{
    private Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, main.class);
            splash.this.startActivity(i);
                                 this.finish()
        }
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(!prefs.getBoolean("first_time", false))
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("first_time", true);
            editor.commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(splash.this, otherSplash.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
                                 this.finish();
        }
        else
        {
            this.setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 2000);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `finish()`... just start the main activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Here's more information on that FLAG

[FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385443/flag-activity-clear-top-in-android)

To be clearer, what I'm suggesting is that you either

1. Make the `Splash` the default activity and in there call the `Main` activity after a timeout, OR, if the splash has already been seen (preference check). (ie, all splash logic is in the `Splash` activity)
2. Have the `Main` activity check to see if `Splash` should be called (preference check) and if so start it using the same `CLEAR_TOP` flag and then have the `Splash` timeout and set the `Main` again using the `CLEAR_TOP` after a couple of seconds.  (This mixes the splash logic in both the `Splash` and the `Main`)

The end result is that `Main` will be the only activity on the stack, once the `Splash` is done.

Comment: That wouldn't actually do anything, as the newly opened Activity would be on top: splash->main. As splash is below main, it would not be closed by this flag.

Comment: using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will make the new activity the ONLY ONE on the stack and it doesn't matter if it was started via Main -> Splash -> Main or Splash -> Main, the end result is that that Main is the only activity on the stack.

Comment: Uh, no. I suggest you reread the link you posted to android developer: if you have stack A, B, C, D, and have D call startActivity on B's class with that flag, the stack becomes A, B - not just B. The flag only kills activities higher than the started one on the stack, not all others.

Comment: I got the impression from reading his comment (start Splash after Main one) that the Activity order was Main -> Splash, and as a result calling Main again with clear top, should remove Splash and only leave Main.  If it goes Splash -> then you are right, the spash would still be around, and the finish() would have to be called after starting the Main (ie, your solution).

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to simply have multiple "Splash" screens, and they have no logic to them, other than just displaying content, then why not just use a single activity and replace the view with a new view for the second splash.  You'd have to do this update on the UI thread as well, so you'd need to either use the an `Handler` or use and `AsyncTask`, or use `View.post()` from a known view element in the current view.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can/should start activity from a thread that is not the UI thread. Change to an AsyncTask, or use a Handler