# Single Sign On as Whats App or Hike or Facebook

Tags: android, authentication

I have made a chatting application, In my application there is a login page, but I don't want to use this page again , once the user has installed the application for the first time. This page should not appear again and again.

I mean when the user first sign in the application, the next time when he comes back the application should directly take him to his home page as in facebook,whatsapp or hike.

I think this approach is known as Single Sign On (SSO) approach. I have traversed the stackoverflow but have not found any relevant link of my interest yet.

Please help me with a good hyperlink or any useful solution so that I can move on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using SharedPreferences would be the way to go. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042302/splashscreen-first-time-with-shared-preferences) thread for help.