# How to remove particular activities from stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

Let's say that I have this stack of activities:

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

The activity `D` has a `Save` button. After click on that button I want to get back two activities in the stack (`C` and `D` are part of some kind of *wizard* so I want to remove them both):

```
A -> B
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch the activity B from D with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`  flag..

```
Intent a = new Intent(this, B.class);
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(a);
```

Comment: And this brings back the B activity and still preserves the A below it?

Comment: yes. Im pretty much sure.. if you had not finished activity `A` when launching `B` from it..

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385443/flag-activity-clear-top-in-android

Answer (score 0):

try finishing them in the onPause() .
I think they will remove the activities from the stack and on the button click call the activity that you want to start using intents

Comment: I think @userSeven7s solution is the best one than this