# How to remove a particular activity from android back stack?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application, i have five activity a,b,c,d,e. User transits in following sequence....
1.  a -> b
2.  b -> c
3.  c -> d
4.  d -> e

up to the activity 'd', if user presses the back button, application should redirect user to the previous activity like d -> c , c -> b and so on...

But when user click's on save button in activity 'd', application will redirect user to the activity 'e'.now if user presses the back button then i want to redirect user to the activity 'a',which is home screen in my application.

I am completely new to the android. I don't know how to achieve this flow.[I tried this solution but it hasn't yielded desired result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544257/how-to-remove-particular-activities-from-stack). and sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in one.

```
// Add activity
public static void addActivities(String actName, Activity _activity) {
    if (Config.screenStack == null)
        Config.screenStack = new HashMap<String, Activity>();
    if (_activity != null)
        Config.screenStack.put(actName, _activity);
}

// Remove Activity
public static void removeActivity(String key) {
    if (Config.screenStack != null && Config.screenStack.size() > 0) {
        Activity _activity = Config.screenStack.get(key);
        if (_activity != null) {
            Config.screenStack.remove(key);
            _activity.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

User add activities before setContentView to add into the stack.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addActivities("DemoActivity", DemoActivity.this)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_feed_post);
}
```

If you want to finish all activity when you exist from app you can [**see this code.**](http://developerandroidguide.blogspot.in/2017/04/how-to-remove-particular-activity-from.html)

Comment: Thanks for solution. your solution is the exact thing that i want. It will give me control over back stack as i want. but where should i implement addActivities() and removeActivity() methods, so that i can use them from any activity? plz, help me....

Comment: You can put this both files in Utils class so that in your activity you can use something like this.
Utils.addActivities("DemoActivity", DemoActivity.this);
Thanks...!

Comment: Just change the Utils.addActivities("activity name", activity.this); according to your activity. Thanks!

Comment: thanks bro!!!! it worked for me....but i edited code a little bit...i posted it in answer.....

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ActivityHandler{
private static HashMap<String, Activity> screenStack;

// Add activity
public static void addActivities(String actName, Activity _activity) {
    if (screenStack == null) {
        screenStack = new HashMap<String, Activity>();
    }

    if (_activity != null && !screenStack.containsKey(actName))
        screenStack.put(actName, _activity);
}

// Remove Activity
public static void removeActivity(String key) {
    if (screenStack != null && screenStack.size() > 0) {
        Activity _activity = screenStack.get(key);
        if (_activity != null && !_activity.isDestroyed() )
        {
            _activity.finish();
            screenStack.remove(key);
        }
    }
}}
```

In my Application...
i used following lines to add or remove activity from stack....
To add activity....
`ActivityHandler.addActivities("CheckoutActivity",CheckoutActivity.this);`

To remove Activity...
`ActivityHandler.removeActivity("CheckoutActivity");`