# Stop going on Refreshed page once we exit

Tags: android, refresh

I have two pages 1.MainActivity 2.Next page.I am refreshing Next page after every 10 seconds.The problem is once I click back and come to Main Activity page it goes again in Next page as it get refreshed.I dont want it to go directly to Next page.I have tried with onBackPressed button but it does not work.
Following is my code:-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Next.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**NextPage.java**

```
public class Next extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.next);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagev);

         Toast.makeText(Next.this, "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 10000);




    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ram.refresh.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/hello"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:text="Next page"
        android:layout_below="@+id/hello"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**next.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imagev"
        android:src="@drawable/smiley"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Simple and standard solution create a stack of activity using array list. [Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326642/how-to-remove-a-particular-activity-from-android-back-stack/38326848#38326848)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            finish();
        }
```

Have only finish() in onBackPressed, remove `super.onBackPressed();` try it & let me know

Comment: No its still going on Next page.