# Why does FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP not work?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

As the title says, Why `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` or `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` won't work?

I have 3 Activities let us say A, B and C.

When I am trying to launch Activity A from C with code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, A.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

It simply starts Activity A but doesn't clear the top.! -_-

I have also tried using `setFlags()`.

I read different questions on SO about this problem, but I couldn't find the right answer. >_<

Somebody please help!

**Edit**

Code for onBackPressed() in activity 'A' as requested by @codeMagic.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(wvLogin.canGoBack())
        wvLogin.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it clear the top?

Comment: What do you mean how? When A is lauched, pressing back button then should exit the app but intean in this case, C comes to focus from background.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by "how". I just needed to make sure that your definition of how was the same as mine before looking at it further.

Comment: Do you override `onBackPressed()` in A?

Comment: @codeMagic : yes! but it is for webview to go back if possible or else just super.onBackPressed() !

Comment: You should possibly edit with that code. Something there isn't right. What if you take that out?

Comment: sure! would it help if I post it here?

Comment: Edit your question and add it there

Comment: Is "A" already present in the task stack? I mean, did you launch startActivity(C), directly or indirectly, from A?

Comment: @matiash : 'A' finished it self after performing a specific task and launches 'B' then 'B' launched 'C'. So only 'B' & 'C' are present in task stack but now 'A'!

Comment: @ashu Then FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will not work. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: @matiash : in last comment i meant but not 'A' instead of but now 'A'. Please note it and I read on developers site but using new task along with clear top also won't work!

Comment: @ashu Got it. Wrote an answer below, hope it's useful.

Comment: When you start `A` with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is there an instance of activity `A` still active in the stack? I mean, when you start `B` from `A`, do you call `finish()` on `A` or not?

Comment: @David Wasser : yes. I do call `finish()` on `A` when I start `B`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From the documentation for [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP):

> If set, **and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task**, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.

As you added in your comment, the activity A has been finished before calling B, so this situation doesn't apply. A new instance of activity A will be launched instead.

As I see it, you have two options here:

1) Use the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flags. This will start activity A as the root of the stack. It works, but any other activities in the stack will be lost. Assuming A was the first activity (or at least, that you are not interested in any previous activities in the task stack) then it doesn't matter. *Note: CLEAR_TASK requires API Level 11.*

2) Another possible solution (in case the previous assumption is not true) would be to not use intent flags at all:

- B starts C with `startActivityForResult()`.
- Instead of calling A, C finishes, having set a result for B indicating that A must be launched.
- In `B.afterActivityResult()`, finish B and launch A.

Comment: Another option would be to leave activity A in the stack (don't call finish() when launching other activities). This will allow you to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. However you'll need to deal with users possible BACKing into activity A.

Comment: what if I had some more activities before A as in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111261/flag-activity-clear-top-does-not-work-as-expected), and I had to preserve them in stack? NEW_TASK fails there, right?

Comment: Man, I love you. I tried about a dozen combinations to close the fu**ing custom chrome tab. Damn 3 days. And only this Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK worked for me.

Comment: The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | ...CLEAR_TASK` worked, but it gives the illusion as if you switched to a new app. Doesn't feel good imo.

I prefer something like this: `intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
activity.startActivity(intent)
activity.finish()`

Answer (score 12):

You are missing the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag

Try this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, A.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 6):

You used a diferrent intent: use the one you initialized:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, A.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); \\WRONG;;
  startActivity(i);
```

**solution:**

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); \\RIGHT;;
```

You could either put a noHistory true to the Activity A in the manifest

```
android:noHistory=true
```

Comment: Why set noHistory to activity 'A' when it is working fine? I have problems with 'B' & 'C' since they are not getting finished in background!

Comment: Thanks @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: android:noHistory="true" was the perfect answer, a one-liner!