# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP does not work as expected

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 4 activities A, B, C, D, E with each declared as `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and A being `parentActivity` of B, and B being parent Activity of C, in manifest.

Now user navigated to E like this: A > B > C > D > E.
And I have a button in E with the following onClickListener

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(E.this, C.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**What I need?** (Also according to documentation, if I understood it right, this should happen)

- Activities D and E should be cleared from stack
- Activity C should be resumed receiving the intent (as singleInstance is set, it will not be created newly)

  > I want this stack: C | B | A

**What's happening?**

- Activity C is resumed receiving the intent
- Activities D and E are **NOT** cleared from stack. I can click back button again and again to see E, D, B, A.

  > I get this stack: C | E | D | B | A

PS: My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718356/flag-activity-clear-top) however, the answers given there does not suit this question. Some answers I found there and elsewhere:

1. I can't use NEW_TASK flag, as I need to keep A, B in stack alive.
2. I can't use startActivityForResult() on D and then finish() it which in fact is a hack, as I have other decisive factors in E such as delivering the intent to some other activity depending on user input.
3. I can't finish() activity D, while delivering intent to E, and then finish() E while hitting C, which would actually solve the problem. But, if back is pressed on E, i want it go back to D and not C.
4. When I try finish() on E as soon as I do `startactivity(intent)` after setting flags, it just finishes E, but not D.

Comment: Can you try to change launchMode from `singleInstance` to `singleTask`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_launchMode) for singleInstance:

> If this activity tries to start a new activity, that new activity will
>   be launched in a separate task.

So, your activity D is launched as the new task, and that's why it is not deleted.

Answer (score 8):

Artem Mostyaev's comment solves the puzzle! Use `singleTask`

> So what exactly was the **mistake**?

When `singleInstance` is used as `launchMode`, and when an activity is launched, Android makes sure that it is launched in a new task as if `NEW_TASK` flag is added, with itself being the only activity inside it.

So when user navigated to E, the stack was never like [ A | B | C | D | E ]
Instead there were five different tasks like [A] [B] [C] [D] [E].

And when I tried E > C with `CLEAR_TOP`, it indeed searched for C in its task and tried to clear all activities after C. But C was never there in the task where E resides.

So it tried launching a new activity C, but then as I set `launchMode` to `singleInstance`, it had no way other than bringing [C] front while leaving other tasks untouched.

> So how `singleTask` worked?

It created the stack like I wanted [ A | B | C | D | E ] and `CLEAR_TOP` worked as expected. Done!

Comment: Great explanation! More better than mine :)