# Switching to another activity takes time

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. switching from one activity to another activity takes time .I don't know why it takes time.Here is my code ,

```
Uri uri = host.getUri();
            Intent contents = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            contents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            contents.setClass(HostListActivity.this, SessionNameSGLOSActivity.class);
            Intent intentConfigurationList = new Intent(HostListActivity.this, SessionNameSGLOSActivity.class);
            intentConfigurationList.putExtra("hostId", host.getId());
            intentConfigurationList.putExtra("hostIp", host.getHostname());
            intentConfigurationList.putExtra("sessionName", host.getSessionName());
            intentConfigurationList.putExtra("connectionName", host.getConnectionName());
            intentConfigurationList.putExtra("uri", host.getUri().toString());
            intentConfigurationList.putExtra("nickName", host.getNickname());
            LogEvent.Log(TAG, "uri" + host.getUri());
            startActivity(intentConfigurationList);
          //  HostListActivity.this.startActivity(intentConfigurationList);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

I have used  overridePendingTransition(0, 0); even it is slower.Please give some suggestions

Comment: Why you need this line contents.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);?
And instead of sending all data like this why can't you send "host" model class only?

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP , this is to clear  the notifications ..

Comment: Please check what this flag means Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP then use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718356/why-does-flag-activity-clear-top-not-work. Try to clear concepts first