# Should I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP in this case? how to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP intent flag?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

In my app I have the following `Activity` flow:
`LoginActivity` > `DashboardActivity` > (if user opts to change their password) > `ChangePasswordActivity`

If the user successfully changes their password, I'd like to send them back to the very first Activity which is `LoginActivity`. I would like to `pop` `DashboardActivity` in the process to prevent any unwanted lingering Activities.

Is it correct to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to start a new `LoginActivity` in this case? I'd like to know which flags are appropriate in this scenario.

For what it's worth, my `DashboardActivity` has a `launchMode` set to `singleTop` in my `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: This answer explains it. In short if you already have login screen in the backstack and want to lauch it without resetting the stack then clear_top would be ideal. Still read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23718678/2936153

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385443/flag-activity-clear-top-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If that was my task, I'd check myself. Isn't it more exciting to discover it yourself?

Comment: you can use finishAffinity in place of finish but yes it will create new instance of Login Activity as well. check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to just clear the previous activities from stack and
>   launch login activity just do this

in `manifest` file your login activity should be like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

After changing password launch the login `activity` with following tags

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ChangePassword.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

By setting flag to `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`
all the previous activities will be cleared from stack.

for more info check this 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent
From the official documentation - `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>
> For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D.
>   If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the
>   component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive
>   the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.

Answer (score 1):

> LoginActivity > DashboardActivity > (if user opts to change their password) > ChangePasswordActivity

- In order to clear task and intent to LoginActivty you should use

  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

> Is it correct to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to start a new LoginActivity in this case? I'd like to know which flags are appropriate in this

- FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will clear everything from the stack and make
  the new activity as root task. In your case, there is no previous
  activity for LoginActivity it will also work but not advisable.

> For what it's worth, my DashboardActivity has a launchMode set to singleTop in my AndroidManifest.

- It will not be useful in your case though you get detail of “LaunchMode" here https://blog.mindorks.com/android-activity-launchmode-explained-cbc6cf996802
- Also check
  https://blog.mindorks.com/android-task-and-back-stack-review-5017f2c18196
  for details