# Logging user out Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a social app with a login/Registration system and I am having trouble logging the user out.

When I click the logout button I want to unset the username and clear the entire session of the user so that they go back to the `LoginActivity` class. Right now when I go to the profile activity and click logout I go straight back to the Home Activity which is only suppose to be for user who are logged in. I've been trying since yesterday and still nothing. Can someone help me ?

Login activity:

```
//SharedPreferences preferences;

private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

private Button LoginButton;
private EditText LoginUsername, LoginPassword;
private TextView NeedNewAccountLink;
private static final String PREF_LOGIN = "LOGIN_PREF";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_LOGIN, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

}

LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    LoginUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
    LoginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    NeedNewAccountLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.need_new_account_link);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

    editor.putString("username", String.valueOf(LoginUsername));
    editor.putString("pw", String.valueOf(LoginPassword));
    editor.apply();

    if (LoginUsername != null) {

        editor.remove("username");
        editor.remove(String.valueOf(sharedPreferences));
        editor.remove("pw");
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();

        SendUserToHomeActivity();
    }

private void SendUserToHomeActivity() {

    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}

public void OnLogin(View view) {

    String username = LoginUsername.getText().toString();
    String pw = LoginPassword.getText().toString();

    String type = "login";

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, pw);

}
```

profile activity:

```
    LogoutButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().clear().apply();

        sharedPreferences.edit().remove("username").apply();
        sharedPreferences.edit().remove("pw").apply();

        editor.remove("username");
        editor.remove("pw");
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();

        finish();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);

    });
```

Comment: With the "finish()" method you are clearing the current activity (ProfileActivity) from the stack and You are invoking the Intent from "ProfileActivity" which doesn't exist anymore. Just keep the "finish()" below your Intent invocation.

Comment: In addition to the previous answer-  don't use SharedPreferences.apply, use commit().  Apply is asynchronous, and it may not be written to disk by the time you launch the login activity.  In that case you could go straight to the home page.

Comment: @GabeSechan I tried this           `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().clear().commit();`

Comment: and it still didn't work

Comment: I do not understand why you are using remove and clear in same time. Use remove when you want to remove a specific key. In your case just use editor.clear().apply(). And make sure your editor object is referencing same shared pref in both activity

Comment: @crack_head that didn't change anything

Comment: can you paste both activity?

Comment: @crack_head which two activities ?

Comment: LoginActivity and ProfileActivity

Answer (score 1):

```
LogoutButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {

    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit().clear().apply();

    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("username").apply();
    sharedPreferences.edit().remove("pw").apply();

    editor.remove("username");
    editor.remove("pw");
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);

});
```

Remove the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag will solve your problem. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718356/why-does-flag-activity-clear-top-not-work).

Answer (score 0):

I believe to get text from edit text you need

> LoginUsername.getText().toString()

and Checking EditText "LoginUsername" against If condition will never yield null unless
it points to wrong ID

Try proceeding with appropriate changes in below code block

```
    LoginUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username);
    LoginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    NeedNewAccountLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.need_new_account_link);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

    editor.putString("username", String.valueOf(LoginUsername));
    editor.putString("pw", String.valueOf(LoginPassword));
    editor.apply();

    if (LoginUsername != null) {

        editor.remove("username");
        editor.remove(String.valueOf(sharedPreferences));
        editor.remove("pw");
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();

        SendUserToHomeActivity();
    }
```