# Activities are always available

Tags: java, android, android-activity

after pressing a button to switch to another activity Im sing the following two lines of code

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddNewAccount.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It successfully changes the activity but the problem is that if I change a lot of activities, by pressing the back arrow of the phone Im going again through all those activities.

Is there a way to avoid this kind of "activities stacking"?

Comment: You can change the kind of behaviour you get on back presses - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Comment: Just add finish(); after startActivity(intent); it will destroy your current activity instead of pausing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does FLAG\_ACTIVITY\_CLEAR\_TOP not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718356/why-does-flag-activity-clear-top-not-work)