# Changing activities with intent does not work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

It should work but it does not. I have an application with some activities. In example activity A and B. Order is A ->(some operation)->B->(some operation)->A...
I start a new activities in this way:

```
//onClick method in A Activity
public void goToB(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,BActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

//onClick method in B Activity
public void goToA(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

I want to finish previous activities, so this is not solution in my case. I checked some answers here, in stackoverflow but they does not help in here.

Logcat says:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    at some places
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at some places
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at some places
```

Has anyone an idea what I am doing wrong? I think it's quite simple thing to do, but maybe I am misunderstanding finish() or startActivity() methods.

EDIT:
One thing I forgot: starting a new activity works "in forward", so from A->B. From B->A it crashes.

Comment: post the view-(or button) that you click to start activity.. i'm referring to xml

Comment: It's normal button with android:onClick="goToA" / "goToB" in this case.

Comment: Your posted code and error message have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace from your crash. And the relevant code where it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it that way, try doing it this way:

```
public void goToA(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AActvity.class);
    intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can read about what the flag does [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385443/flag-activity-clear-top-in-android), but it'll get rid of the extra instances running once you change the activity.

However, I will mention that you must have other issues if you're getting OutOfBounds.

Comment: This works even worse. There are still the same errors and 'back' button now works (I do not want it to work [of course I always can override it and write an empty method]).

Comment: @Charliee you have other issues in your code then that aren't related to the "finish" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that can be done by `Intent`, better is use `finish();` to return to `A` activity;

```
//onClick method in A Activity
public void goToB(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(this,BActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

}

//onClick method in B Activity
public void goToA() {    
this.finish();
}
```

The stack you will have less space.