# Is there a better way to finish the activity from another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities FirstActivity, SecondActivity and ThirdActivity. FirstActivity leads to SecondActivity  which leads to ThirdActivity. I would like to be able to move back and forth between FirstActivity and SecondActivity  , FirstActivity and ThirdActivity.

Here is what I have implemented :

**FirstActivity :**

In FirstActivity I have an onClick method 'goToSecondActivity', which starts SecondActivity

```
 public void goToSecondActivity(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        final EditText firstText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstText);
        String userMessage = firstText.getText().toString();
        if(!"".equals(userMessage))
        i.putExtra("firstMessage",userMessage);

        startActivity(i);
    }
```

[image]

**SecondActivity :**

In SecondActivity again I have an onClick method 'goToThirdActivity', which starts ThirdActivity

```
public void goToThirdActivity(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(this , ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

[image]

**ThirdActivity :**

In ThirdActivity I have two onClick method 'backToFirstActivity' and 'backToPreviousActivity' on two different buttons

[image]

On ThirdActivity when I click On 'Back To First Activity' button , I want to go back to the FirstActivity.

**What I have Done :**

**SecondActivity :**

I have declared static variable

```
static SecondActivity secondActivityMain;
```

And assign it in onCreate method :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ---
       ---
        secondActivityMain = this;
       ---
       ---

}
```

**ThirdActivity :**

Using static variable finishes the SecondActivity **"SecondActivity.secondActivityMain.finish();"**

```
 public void backToFirstActivity(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Third: finished second activity ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SecondActivity.secondActivityMain.finish();
                ThirdActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 2000);

    }
```

**My Questions Are :**

**1. Is there a better way to finish the activity from another activity?**

**2. Is this way is correct?**

Comment: Please check FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385443/flag-activity-clear-top-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385443/flag-activity-clear-top-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there a better way to finish the activity from another activity?

**Yes**, What you have done is used `static` instace on `Activity` which could easily lead to memory leak issues. **Its always good practice to use  `static` keyword only if necessary and very carefully as well.**

Better way would use `BroadCastreceiver`

So, what you need to do is create broadcast receiver in your first and second activity and whenver you wants to finish those activity. use `sendBroadCast(..)`  method.

you need to search it out how `Broadcastreceiver` works in android.

> 2. Is this way is correct?

**No**, The way you did is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have search a lot to convert my example to work with broadcast ,  but I am not getting how to convert my SecondActivity to receive a broadcast. Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go FirstActivity from ThirdActivity use this this intent with flag "FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP" it will clear Third and second Activity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

For FirstActivity In Manifeast file if you are specified android:launchMode="singleTop" then OnCreate() method will not be called when you are came from ThirdActivity to FirstActivity 
if you are not specified lanuhMode in manifeast file then OnCreate will be called Again