# Android: Back to some Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

[image]

Activity1 (not finish) can start Activity2 , Activity2 (not finish) can start Activity3.
And Activity2 and 3 can back to previous activity using

```
super.onBackPressed();
this.finish();
```

And I want to know how Activity3 back to Activity1(***not refresh***) directly and release the memory of Activity2?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342761/how-do-you-use-intent-flag-activity-clear-top-to-clear-the-activity-stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity3.this, Activity1.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will make the `Activity1` be at the top of the backstack, killing all `Activities` on top of it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     startActivity(new Intent(this, UI.class)
     .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
 return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try super.finish(); to close 2nd activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to come back to the existing activity you can use a unique ID and onActivityResult if resultData == ID --> close the second activity (for user it will be seemed like coming back from third activity to the first).

To learn more information about stack of activities, visit [google site](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Also maybe [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is suitable for you - and you can simply walk through fragment stack.

Answer (score 0):

Activity 2

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class);
startActivityforResult(intent,0);
```

When coming back from Activity3 override `onBackPressed()` and set result when needed

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
```

then override onActivityResult() in Activity2

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 0) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
                finish();
        }
    }
```

This will finish second activity, when result is set. Otherwise you can navigate back and forth like any normal activities.