# Exit Android App From Specified Point

Tags: c#, android, mono, back-button

Ok first, let me say, I have read many threads here, and elsewhere, but can't seem to find the answer here. I realize that "exiting" and app is frowned upon, but here is my scenario, what should I do?

- First launch, customer sees login screen, with option to remember me
- after Login, menu activity is activated
- I want the back button to exit the App from the menu, not go back to the login activity that the app starts on. I have a menu option to "logout" if they need to get back to the login screen, otherwise I want to just exit the app on back press from the menu activity.

Is there a way, in my override of `OnBackButtonPressed`, that I can trigger the app to exit?

Comment: If your login screen is a fragment and the app is launched in the same activity, you can simply not call `addToBackStack()` when removing the login fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not start the activity C with a flag in your Intent? I don't think you will need to override the `OnBackButtonPressed`. Too complex for a rather simple solution.

For example:

```
Intent showActivity = new Intent(Sender.this, Receiver.class);
showActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(showActivity);
```

This way, when the user presses the back button, he will *exit* the application and not go back to the *Login Screen*.

If you still need to override the *Back Button*, then try this example:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent a = new Intent(this,A.class);
    a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(a);
    return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Props to [**bitestar**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880047/bitestar) for this piece of code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398171/450534

Answer (score 0):

I have read all of your requirements,you need to just manipulate the flow of application as I have shown below to achieve it.I hope it will be helpful to you.

Inside your login screen which is going to be launched while starting the application,

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    UTILS.Log_e(TAG, "onCreate");




        initialize();

    //check for configuration
//here you need to check,whether user has been logged in already or not
    if(!CONSTANTS.isConfigured)
    {
//display login dialog if user has not been logged in already

        displayLoginDialog();
    }
    else
    {

//move to Home screen if user has already logged in
        i.setClass(mContext, HomeActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Inside your Home screen,

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    exitApp();
}

private void exitApp()
{
    i.setClass(mContext, ExitActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}


//call logout function as per your requirement

    private void logout()
{
    i.setClass(mContext, LoginActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}
```

Inside your ExitActivity,

```
   public class ExitActivity extends Activity{

    private static final String TAG = "ExitActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        moveTaskToBack(true);
        finish();
        }

}
```

**NOTE:**
in above codes, I have used `i.setClass(context,destination_class_name)` in which `i` is the instance of `Intent`.

Inside your manifest,

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.HomeActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.ExitActivity" >
    </activity>
```

Kindly let me know if you face any problems or if you don't understand any point in above code.