# Flag Activity Clear Top destroys target activity and than creating it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I am watching a behavior of Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.

For example i have three activities 
A,B and C
Now Flow is A -> B -> C

Now when i am starting A from C with this flag with following code.

```
 Intent intent_to_a=new Intent(C.this,A.class);
                intent_to_home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent_to_a);
```

AFAIK, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP should remove B and should resume the A .It also does the same but in a strange way.
It removes B , than removes A than creates A.
Method onDestroy of A is also being called.
Can anyone tell me is it proper or not?
If i don't want it to get destroy what should i do?

Comment: look into FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, this is closer to what you want http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: yeah,i looked into that too,but i also want B to get destroyed,FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT only put A into top of ActivityStack without removing B.

Comment: maybe you could use LocalBroadCastManager to send a separate intent to B to finish itself and then use Reorder_to_front? I could provide source code if this is something you are interested in

Comment: you mean we could use a separate BroadcastReceiver to just finish B.Is it so?

Comment: correct, but it's actually very easy to do instead of having the BroadcastReceiver as a separate class, you can have it in the activity and dynamically declare it

Comment: sure i will look into that.Would like to see it.

Comment: ok posted solution, goodluck :)

Answer (score 4):

Use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT and then use an intent to tell B to finish.

Activity B:

```
private BroadcastReceiver finishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            finish();
        }
    };
public void onCreate() {
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
                .registerReceiver(finishReceiver ,
                        new IntentFilter("B-finish"));
}
public void onDestroy() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
                finishReceiver );
}
```

Activity C:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(
                new Intent("B-finish"));
Intent intent_to_a=new Intent(C.this,A.class);
                intent_to_home.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                startActivity(intent_to_a);
```

Comment: Hey,i don't find any class such as LocalBroadcastManager in my current android version,i am using android version 2.3.3,api level 10.

Comment: you need to add the support library v4 http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Answer (score 4):

Either, 

**1**. Change the `launchMode` of the Activity A to something else from standard (ie `singleTask` or something). Then your flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will not restart your Activity A.

or,

**2**. Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as your flag. Then it will work the way you desire.

[This question has good discussion on same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342761/how-do-you-use-intent-flag-activity-clear-top-to-clear-the-activity-stack/13474574#13474574)

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) says -

> The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will either receive the new intent you are starting here in its onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new intent. 
> If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().