# How To Close Android Application correctly ?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an application which have 2 button, save and exit. save button to insert sqlite and reset all EditText and listview,Exit button to close my android application.here is my save button code :

```
 btnsaveto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsaveto);
      btnsaveto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //do insert into sqlite
        Globals.mylist.clear();//my listview
        Globals.outletname=null;//my Editext
        Globals.outletid=0;//my Editext
        Globals.notes=null;//my Editext
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
     });
```

and here is my exit button's code:

```
btnexit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexit);
      btnexit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        } );
```

Here is my oncreate activity :

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.entry_to);
      txtoutlet = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtoutlet);
      dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);
      dataSource.open();
      Bundle bun = EntryTO.this.getIntent().getExtras();
          try{
      if (Globals.mylist == null){Globals.mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();}
            id = bun.getLong("id");
            Id=String.valueOf(id);
            description = bun.getString("description");
            qty = bun.getString("qty");
            if(bun.getString("outletname")!=null){
            Globals.outletid = bun.getLong("outletid");
            Globals.outletname = bun.getString("outletname");  
            }
          map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
          if(Globals.mylist.size() == 0){
              if(Id!=null && description!=null && Globals.outletname!=null){
              map1.put("one", Id);
              map1.put("two", description);
              map1.put("three", qty);
              Globals.mylist.add(map1);
              txtoutlet.setText(Globals.outletname);
              }else{
              txtoutlet.setText(Globals.outletname);  
              }
          }else{
          int j=Globals.mylist.size();
          if(Id!=null && description!=null && Globals.outletname!=null){
          map1.put("one", Id);
          map1.put("two", description);
          map1.put("three", qty);
          Globals.mylist.add(j,map1);
          txtoutlet.setText(Globals.outletname);
          }else{
              txtoutlet.setText(Globals.outletname);
              } 
          }
            try {
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(EntryTO.this, Globals.mylist, R.layout.item_to,
                          new String[] {"two", "three"},
                          new int[] {R.id.edtbrandto,R.id.edtqtyto });
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }catch (Exception e) {}
      }catch(NullPointerException e){}
      btnsaveto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsaveto);
      btnsaveto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try{
        String orderid=orderid();
        String orderdate=orderdate();
        String notes = Globals.notes;
        String image = photoToBase64String() ;
        long outletid = Globals.outletid;
        order = dataSource.createorder(orderid, orderdate, notes, image , outletid);
        for(int i=0;i<=Globals.mylist.size()-1;i++){
            map1=Globals.mylist.get(i);
            String Id = map1.get("one");
            String qty = map1.get("three");
        orderdtl = dataSource.createorderdtl(orderid, Id, qty);
        Toast.makeText(EntryTO.this, "Mengisi Data Ke-"+i+", tunggu sebentar..\n" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        Globals.mylist.clear();
        Globals.outletname=null;
        Globals.outletid=0;
        Globals.mPath=null;
        Globals.notes=null;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            }
        }
     });
```

The problem was when I re-open my application, EditText and ListView still fill. Is there something wrong when i reset intent, or I haven't close the app correctly.

NB: I have 3 Activity, and I Declared all of my variable on Globals.java to keep my values on some activity when I get other values on another activity.

Comment: Try adding the flag clear task also to new task flag

Comment: are you filling your `EditText` and `ListView` in the `onCreate()` method?

Comment: @SMR yes you alright..

Comment: whatever you do in the `onCreate()` method then it is going to be executed every time you launch your app. if you dont want the data to be loaded every time then you need to it anywhere else. can you provide the full activity code?

Comment: @WardaLyn if you are filling your `EditText` and `ListView1 in `onCreate` from SQLite then yes whenever you open your app your data will be filled in them autometically.

Comment: @SMR i have add my oncreate activity.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh what should i do? i try to avoid them by reset, and clear all values on globals when i finished insert all values into sqlite.any advice?

Comment: when do you want the data to be shown or hidden to the user?

Comment: if you want to poplate your `EditText` and `ListView` "whenever you want" just add a button and in `onClickListener` query your database. In this case when you press `Button` your activity will load data from database. make sure to set text of your `EditText` and `ListView` after query ie in the `onClickListner`.

Comment: @SMR Only when I open my application, all of my editText and listview on my parent activity cleared. I need to fill them up with new values.could you help me

Comment: All right I can help you only if I understand what are you trying to do in your app. If I clearly understand what you are trying to achieve then  i will be able to help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342761/how-do-you-use-intent-flag-activity-clear-top-to-clear-the-activity-stack

Comment: if filling my edittext and listview in onCreate makes all of them filled in, where should i do?@SMR

Answer (score 1):

you can not close your application. android does not allow this. you can invoke home intent sot that your application will get back in background.

Comment: thank you for your information.This will really help my learning process

Answer (score 1):

If your application contains only one activity then you should consider using finish() method or super.onBackPressed().

If your application has more than one activity and lets say you have login page or splash activity (Whichever is first activity to launch application) lets call it A, then you call
acitivty A with FLAG_CLEAR_TOP and pass some value through bundle and in A check if you want to exit app or not, if yes then finish that activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: system.exit should not be used. it make your application not to work correctly.

Comment: I agree with @wqrahd.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an activity stack that:

1. pushes new activity when it is created
2. pops activity when it is destroyed

When you need to close application, you call finish() on every activity in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the below code to exit from recent.

activity android:name=".AppName" android:excludeFromRecents="true"