# Android stack is not getting clear

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have got stuck in situation please help me .Here is the problem .I have a menu screen in my application.Now have given option to go back to menu to all screens that has not come directly from menu screen .For example I go to Activity B like Menu ->Activity A -->Activity B. Now I have written on pressing backtoMenu button.

```
this.finish();
startActivity(new Intent(SelectStateActivity.this,MenuScreen.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

I am not finishing Activity A because I want to be on activity A when I press back button on activity B.So it will be on stack when I press menu button on Activity B.
I come to menu screen which is fine but when I press back on menu screen I come to Activity A.Which is not wanted.I also tried

```
this.finish();
startActivity(new Intent(SelectStateActivity.this,MenuScreen.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
```

and

```
  startActivity(new Intent(SelectStateActivity.this,MenuScreen.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

But haven't worked.Please help me.

Comment: If I understand you correctly - You should try to open new activity before close current

Comment: @user974801 Please see the options I have tried.In last option I haven't finish the activity .

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the issue by following solution.

1. Using normal observer pattern which is implemented using core java.
   for observer pattern refer [this](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)
2. Or same pattern implemented in android which is Broadcast receiver.
   In this solution every activity is registered for your custom broadcast Massage and once you launch Menu activity broadcast that message so that registered activities which can listen message and finish itself.

Let me know if you have issue in above.

Comment: Your solution is acceptable but why clear_task and clear_top not working .

Comment: You can check the given link and refer the answer given by Darpan there :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342761/how-do-you-use-intent-flag-activity-clear-top-to-clear-the-activity-stack. BTW if my solution helps you, you can accept or upvote it.