# startActivityForResult usage for 3 activity Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-intentservice

Hey guys I have 3 activity,

Activity A -> Activity B -> Activity C

This flow I want to perform in my application. I want this scenario in my Activity C

Scenario 1

On Back press from Activity C to open Activity B then again back press then open Activity A

Scenario 2

When something submit on Activity C, I want to open Activity A and I want to hide Activity B

So how can I do this through startActivityForResult. I check through this [stackoverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27034053/11560810), but nothing works. Thanks

Comment: Most likely, this should be a single activity with three fragments or composables, rather than three activities.

Comment: It's three activity.

Comment: Yes, but I am suggesting that you rewrite it to be a single activity with three fragments or composables, rather than three activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the 3 activities are opened in order A -> B -> C, so they are in the backstack in that order. You can check the return values from Activity C, and act accordingly.

In Activity C, `setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED)` during `onCreate()`. That will make it the default return value when activity C is closed (back press or otherwise)`.

Then `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)` whenever something is submitted. After that, you can `fininsh()` that activity.

Whenever Activity C get closed, in Activity B `onActivityResult()`, check the return value. If it's `RESULT_OK`, call `finish()` (which will return to Activity A). Otherwise, do nothing, so Activity B will stay open