# Application is crashing when BackPressed on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

When user back press on the login screen of my application application crashes. I use below code to launch my login activity -

```
private void showLoginActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

I do some background operation in this screen through asynctask. I saw the logcat It's showing problem in asynctask as the login activity finishes and the task is still running. How can I resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your logcat entries.

Comment: can u show the error message ....logcat message

Comment: It probably happens because you are referring to objects in your first activity from the asynctask. You can avoid this by finishing tha activity when the task is done.

Comment: why on hell you are using getApplicationContext() inside Activity(assumption after finish() calls)

Answer (score 0):

if how try this please:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. I used some flags to launch login activity. Below are those flags which I used -

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

Comment: of course **it is not a solution** ... it is rather dirt fix ... share logcat's log with us - there should be a real solution ....

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your flags. Probably in your

> intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

i would suggest you  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342761/how-do-you-use-intent-flag-activity-clear-top-to-clear-the-activity-stack) to read and understand.