# Prevent ActionBar back button to recreate the MainActivity

Tags: java, android

How can I prevent the **ActionBar back button** (we gonna say **ABBB**) of my `SecondActivity` to recreate the `MainActivity`when clicked ?

I have a `ListView` in the `MainActivity` and it can be edited using the `SecondActivity`. The problem is that when the user presses the ABBB, the `ListView` is reset to default...

However, when the user clicks my OK button or presses physical back button, there is not any problem because I'm using `finish();`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

If I use this code... :

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case (android.R.id.home):
        finish();
}
```

...there is the same problem because, I guess, this method is called *after* "Android's code".

How can I totally override Android ABBB's clicked code to set it to just call `finish();` ?

Comment: `switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case (android.R.id.home):
        finish();
}` Should not behave the same way! can you post more code from both activities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal scenario is, when are you in the `SecondActivity` (I take it that, this means that you are in Edit mode), and you press the device back button or ABBB, you show a subtle alert to the user saying "do they really want to dismiss the editing", or go ahead and apply the edit done as in the Contacts application.

So that being said, if all you require is to `finish()` the activity on press of ABBB, the code that you shown above should work fine (though you need to put `return true;` after `finish()`). It works for me. Try the below one in your `activity`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed(); // or finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I put `onBackPressed();` because your ABBB with now imitate your device back button.

Comment: I'm not on my computer anymore, so I'll try this tomorrow. Thank you for the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can set your parent activity's launch mode as -

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

that will do all without changing anything.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26251007/609782)